# AntHill? How to add a project to the hill?

Tags: .net, build, anthill

Anybody use AntHillPro for auto builds?   If so, I'm curious how you add a .NET solution/ project to the hill (to be compiled along with everything else, etc.)

This is one of those "had to be done yesterday" things but no one on my team understands how to do this (I'd expect it to be the most basic question anyone would ask when you use a build tool).  So I'm having a look thru the documentation, don't find it immediately helpful / will not give up...but thought I'd ask this forum since everyone is pretty knowledgeable on most programming topics.

I also tried to look up the same info on anthill's site, however to get into their forums they state it may take 24 hours (ridiculous, if you ask me - why would anyone want to buy a product where they share little info up-front to see how it works, etc.)

Anyway onto the docs...but if anyone has any helpful hints it'd be much appreciated - thanks.

Comment: >Anthill Pro is a proprietary project, with a license fee of $2,499 that includes one year of upgrades and 30 days of support.


...... ah, perfect... i'm sure the person that made the decision to ditch cruise control is long gone & we're well out of the 30-day support window.

Answer (score 1):

In fairness, it says "may take" and we're usually quite a bit faster - and we try to spot people asking questions on places like Stack Overflow. There's also a mailing list you can sign up for at lists: http://lists.urbancode.com/mailman/listinfo/anthill-pro

Can I ask which version you are on? Are you on the 2.x version (which had the price you mention back in 2005) or are you on 3.x? The version number is at the bottom of every page. If you're on 3.x, there are steps for executing builds with Visual Studio (dev-env), MSBuild and Nant.

What I would do is copy an existing project, go into the build workflow of the copied project and adjust the source control setting to point at the new project. Then enter the build job(s), remove the builders you don't like and add your .Net builders.

Alternatively, in the docs, I would use the Simple CI Tutorial as a starting place for creating new projects.

If you're on the older 2.x line, I think you'd have to create a basic shell based build for .Net.